# Adding variable inside .find() with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
.find("[data-list='read']")
```

and I want to add a JS variable inside, something like this:

```
.find("[data-list=''+ $variable +'']")
```

Obviously, the two single quotations won't work in this case. Do I need to escape the single quotations in some way? What's the approach in JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** or just concatenate the strings preserving the `"text'" + var + "'text"` style.

```js
var variable = 'myText';
var tlSelector = `[data-list='${variable}']`;
var concStrings = "[data-list='" + variable +"']";

console.log(tlSelector);
console.log(concStrings);
```

Comment: Please post code here rather than post external links. Thanks!

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Updated

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation should look like this:

```
"[data-list='" + $variable + "']"
```

To break it down: string1 + string2 + string3 where

```
string1 = "[data-list='"
string2 = $variable
string3 = "']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to concatenate variable like this:

```
.find("[data-list='" + read + "']")
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".